# Haskell UArray variable type

Tags: haskell

I am attempting to write a function using UArrays that are very general. I would like the type signature:

```
myFunction :: a -> b -> ((UArray Int a), (UArray Int b))
```

However, a and b are too general. I would like them to be one of the possible instances of `IArray UArray a`. Is there some deriving type that will allow me to specify this? For example, if Num were a valid instance I could do:

```
myFunction :: (Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> ((UArray Int a), (UArray Int b))
```

Does it make sense what I am trying to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is correct. Sorry, `IArray UArray a` is what I would like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to repeat constraints from array methods you are going to use, such as `array` etc. Since your indexes are fixed and we know they're instance of `Ix`, we only need to add `IArray` constraints:

```
myFunction :: (IArray UArray a, IArray UArray b)
           => a -> b -> ((UArray Int a), (UArray Int b))
```

For this, you need the [FlexibleContexts](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.2.1/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html#instance-rules) (see section *7.6.3.2. Relaxed rules for instance contexts*) language extension.

You could also think about generalizing your function to arbitrary arrays (not just `UArray`s

```
myFunction1 :: (IArray arr a, IArray arr b)
            => a -> b -> ((arr Int a), (arr Int b))
```

or perhaps even to arbitrary indexes:

```
myFunction2 :: (IArray arr a, IArray arr b, Ix i)
            => a -> b -> ((arr i a), (arr i b))
```

(For these 2 variants, you don't need the extension.)

Since probably you're using `UArray`s for speed, I'd suggest adding [`INLINE`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.4/html/users_guide/pragmas.html#inline-pragma) pragma so that your function gets optimized for the particular data types at the place you use it. That can make a significant speed improvement.

Comment: This works! Thank you. One think to note is that you need to use the `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}` flag.

Comment: @Joe You were faster than me, I was just adding this note to the answer.